# Flatten Pandas DataFrame adding a suffix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
 POS    Price    Cost (...)
10122    100      20
10123    500      5
(...)
```

I would like to pivot rows and columns, obtaining a single line, adding a suffix as:

```
Price_POS10122    Cost_POS10122    Price_POS10123    Cost_POS10123 (...)
100                    20                500                5

(...)
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

let's unstack:

```
df=df.set_index('POS').unstack().to_frame().T
df.columns=[f"{x}_POS{y}" for x,y in df.columns]
```

output of df:

```
   Price_POS10122   Price_POS10123  Cost_POS10122   Cost_POS10123
0   100             500             20              5
```